# Detecting irregular lines/polyline in matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am quite new to matlab and image processing

What I am trying to achieve is to detect irregular lines in an image. for example, in the following image, there are 4 polylines:

[image]

My goal is to get a set of pixel points representing these 4 irregular lines/poly line . something like this.

[image]

I have read through some topics like edge detection (canny) and hough line detection. I applied them but I do not know how to tune them for my purpose, and I am not sure whether I am going the right direction. I would appreciate if you can give me some advices or point me to useful resources/articles/algorithms/libraries. 
-------------------Edit ------------------------------------

Thank you for all your input, i think it gets me to the right direction.
My question is simpler then you might think. I am not trying to detect whether the lines are irregular or not, but just to get the pixels of detected lines.

In matlab, I followed this routes:

rgb2gray -> 2bw -> bwmorgh(skeletonize) -> bwconncomp(get connected components)

The result looks good for me at the moment, thanks.

Comment: I guess it's not always black lines on clean white background right?

Comment: Hi, the real problem would be a lot more complicated. It is about detecting lines on a paper map. But currently I am trying to start with this simple  scenario. I would be very happy if I can solve this problem first.

Comment: I think you can also use `eccentricity` from `regionprops` in MATLAB. If eccentricity is 1, then it is a line.

Comment: Could you, once you have solved it, post the solution you actually ended up with, please. It would be interesting to see which solution you finally chose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this scenario

after simple binary thresholding, skeletonize the image, label line regions, create straight lines using their end points (an end point of a skeleton has only 1 neighbour)

find max distance from the skeleton to this line, if it is higher than a certain threshold (say, line length/dmax < 20), then that skeleton is an irregular line

http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/

[image: dmax]

for paper map scenario

i guess you want to find specific roads or borders. at least they have different colors and width, you may want to smooth aggressively and apply color threshold after. still you need to work with a thousand different maps to find a generic algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, sepecially  for pointing me to thinning/sceletonize.